# Is there a word for the number of people going in and out of a building?

Tags: word-choice

With approximately 10,000 visitors and residents going in and out of the building.

I want to replace the phrase going in and out with one word, maybe flow will work? I don't know if there's such a word as people flow.

Comment: What sort of research have you done?  Try the verb _transit_.

Comment: 'Enter the building daily' is all you need. Whether they leave or not is not a question. No need to start with 'With.'

Comment: There's **footfall**.

Comment: I've edited your question. Number, not amount. You can find out why in many posts on this site. And "goes" is ungrammatical — "going". Let's get the basics right first.

Answer (score 3):

**Traffic** or **foot traffic** are often used for that.

Traffic: *the volume of customers visiting a business establishment* [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traffic)

Answer (score 1):

"Approximately 10,000 visitors and residents ***visit*** the building."

"Approximately 10,000 guests and residents ***visit*** the building."

> **Visit**
> [viz-it]
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to go to and stay with (a person or family) or at (a place) for a short time for reasons of sociability, politeness, business, curiosity, etc.
> 2. to come or go to
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/visit?s=t)

Referring to the temporary nature of visit, I think it accounts for both coming and going and the general transitive nature of the people at the building.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately 10,000 visitors and residents **stream** to the building.

**Stream**

OED definition:

A mass of people or things moving continuously in the same direction

Example: ‘I do not expect to see lines of refuges streaming to the borders,’ said Reams.’

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stream)

OR

A massive **influx** of approximately 10,000 visitors and residents to the building.

**Influx**

OED definition:

An arrival or entry of large numbers of people or things.

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/influx)

The words **stream** and **influx** can be used to discard "going in an out."